# Functional analysis summary

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

Anyone knows a good summary containing the most important definitions and theorems about functional analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Georgei E. Shilov's [***Elementary Functional Analysis***, 2nd Ed.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486689239) (Dover books, 1996) would be a great start, and cheap, as far as textbooks go!

For a *very brief* (17 page) "summary" pdf document, written and posted by Dileep Menon and which might be of interest: [***An introduction to functional analysis***](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Menon.pdf). It contains both definitions and theorems, as well as a list of references.

See also the lists of definitions and theorems covered in Gilliam's course on functional analysis: [here](http://texas.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/f06/m5340_f06/thms_functional_5341.pdf), and [here](http://texas.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/f06/m5340_f06/thms_functional.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! but I was searching for an homepage, just to find the theorems and definitions written down in compact form.

Comment: Yes it was really cheap! I will by it also